# Redirect parent domain to subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I know there are a lot of similar questions, still I need your help.

My main site (maindomain.com) is in the root directory of the server public_html.

I have created a subdomain example.maindomain.com and it is in the sub-folder public_html/example

I parked the domain example.net and I need it to point to public_html/example and I need to create the rewrite rules in .htaccess

Still, I maindomain.com to work normally, not redirect from it.

I tried but no success:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.net$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /example/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Why do you need rewrite rules? you need to configure new virtualhost only

Comment: I really believe I cannot do that with my hosting plan and from my cPanel....

Comment: Besides, the problem is that the domain itself does not belong to this hosting and this hosting plan has no add-on domains, so I try to overcome these obstacles......